# Store for loop results as a variable in php

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I have this

```
    <?php
    $articlesCount = count($articles);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $articlesCount; $i++) {
      //would like to store result as a variable for use later
    }
    ?>
```

I would like to store the results of the for loop in a variable so that I can use that variable later to call on the desired information from the loop. At this time the syntax eludes me. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have nothing inside  your for loop. Perhaps some example code in there would help with the solution. We don't know what you are trying to do. Possible solutions would be output buffering or simple concatenation of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the stuff you want to save in an array. As `$i` increases in size all data will be put in different indexes.

```
<?php
$articlesCount = count($articles);
$result = []; // Empty array

for ($i = 0; $i < $articlesCount; $i++) {
  $result[$i] = $variable; // Variable = whatever you want to save
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to save a result for each iteration or just a global result.

If you want to save a result for each iteration, you can use an array.
For instance, this will generate the array with values 0,2,4,6...

```
<?php
$articlesCount = count($articles);
$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $articlesCount; $i++) {
  $result[$i] = $i * 2;
}
echo $result[2]; //will show "4" because the it is the 3rd element in the array (we start counting at 0, not 1)
?>
```

If you want to save a global result, for instance the sum of all elements of an array:

```
<?php
$articlesCount = count($articles);
$result = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $articlesCount; $i++) {
  $result = $result + $i ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have it at `$articles` variable. Why you need to reassign it to another variable? You can access the array information by providing the keys, such as `$articles[1]`. If it is a  array of object, you can access the data by `$articles[1]->name`.